# Homologically-trivial codimension-2 submanifolds must bound codimension-1 submanifolds

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

I'm not sure about the exact statement, but I've heard that a homologically-trivial codimension-2 submanifolds must bound codimension-1 submanifolds. Is there a reference a proof for this statement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the setting of smooth manifolds (judging by the tags this is the case you are interested in), see Theorem 3 on page 50 of

*Kirby, Robion C.*, [**The topology of 4-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0089031), Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1374. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. vi, 108 p. DM 25.00 (1989). [ZBL0668.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0668.57001).

I am not sure about the topological category (PL should work the same). I remember, Mike Miller wrote a more detailed account of this proof (and mentioned it in one of the MSE questions), I just forgot where it was. You may want to ask Mike directly, he is at  Columbia U.

**Edit.** In the answer I was assuming that you are using homology with integer coefficients and your codimension 2 submanifold $M\subset N^n$ is closed, connected and oriented, and $N$ is also oriented (not sure if this assumption is essential here, but it is used in the proof). Then the fundamental class $[M]$ of $M$ is well-defined and the condition that $[M]=0\in H_{n-2}(N)$ is well-posed.

Here is the proof taken from Kirby's book:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course, my bad.  In light of your edit, we can stop the conversation if you prefer, but I still find the result quite hard to believe.  A corollary of it:  if $M$ is closed, orientable, and has odd Euler characteristic, then any codimension $2$ embedding $M\rightarrow N$ is homologically non-trivial.  (In the case where $M$ is a surface, this result has no content since odd Euler characteristic implies non-orientable for surfaces.)  Or are you only claiming the result for surfaces?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Kirby's proof (almost surely known to Rene Thom) is not that hard, it is a relative version of the fact that homology classes of codimension $\le 2$ in a smooth manifold are represented by smooth embedded submanifolds, which is explained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035792/every-class-in-h-n-1m-mathbbz-represented-by-closed-smooth-orienta?rq=1) answer. Bredon in his G&T book (p. 377) refers to Rene Thom for the absolute result. The relative result is probably due to Thom as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access Kirby's book.  I'm familiar with the argument you linked to - my issue is whether or not $M$ bounds a smooth submanifold, as opposed to some  singular chain.   I've actually got to run now, by I do have access to Bredon, so I'll check it out there.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting that excerpt - that's a nice argument.  I also came up with a characteristic class argument for the corollary I mentioned in my first post.  Namely, the hypothesis implies that the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $M$ cannot all vanish, which implies the same for the normal bundle of $M$, which then implies the existence of a non-trivial Pontryagin class for both $M$ and the normal bundle.  The normal bundle is rank $2$, contradiction.  (This argument neglects the case where the Pontryagin classes were 2-torsion, but it at least made the corollary believable to me.)  Thanks!

Comment: @JasonDeVito You are welcome, Jason!